# Link tag not working with rel="manifest"?

Tags: html, dom, manifest, iphone-standalone-web-app

Following is my code in an HTML page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="manifest" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}manifest.json" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}ng-grid.min.css" />
  </head>
</html>
```

Both `manifest.json` and `ng-grid.min.css` are served from the same static folder.

`ng-grid.min.css` was loaded as soon as the page was rendered but `manifest.json` file is not loaded.

On inspecting using developer tools I couldn't find a request for `manifest.json`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I believe manifest.json gets refreshed once a day in theory. I'm currently trying to work out why mine never seems to get refreshed once a PWA has been installed.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Can you let me know it was resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `'/'` in the statement.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/manifest.json">
```

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake  in the question.Its modified now.'/' is infact included in STATIC_URL.